# "permission denied" when downloading with Transmission

Tags: downloads, bittorrent, transmission

I'm having trouble downloading torrents. A torrent starts off and after a while goes red, saying: "permission denied [file path]". It's the same whether I set a target folder on an USB drive (preferably) or in a folder in the Home directory. I have not changed permissions since installig the OS. Help!

[Ubuntu version: 16.04, 64-bit]

Comment: Could you start transmission from terminal and force the error, to try get more info from it?

Comment: Yes, but I need your help to do that.

Comment: As in: I don't know how to do that :)

Comment: Open a terminal and type transmission then enter. Copy paste all the output you get while you use the program and get the said error

Comment: The reply is quite simple: command unknown.

Comment: Use `transmission-gtk`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I think its about creating new folders in the download folder. The torrent start to work, but when it tries to create a new folder, it gets the Denied access error.

I solved the problem adding the debian-transmission user to the users group.

```
sudo adduser debian-transmission users
```

My download folder has 777 permissions.